# switch/case to strategy pattern

Tags: c#

I am having a huge switch/case statement which I would like to replace with strategy pattern. Each statement has big peace of code doing the specific logic. Does anyone have a good example of using the pattern in such case, or you have any other good solutions to this?

My solution sofar

```
class Context
{
    private readonly List<CalculationUnit> _calculationsUnits;

    public Context()
    {
        _calculationsUnits = new List<CalculationUnit>()
                                 {
                                     new CalculationUnitA("calc1"),
                                     new CalculationUnitB("calc2"),
                                     new CalculationUnitC("calc2")
                                 };
    }

    public int Calculate(string name)
    {
        return (from c in _calculationsUnits where c.Name.Equals(name) select c.Calculate()).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

class CalculationUnit
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public CalculationUnit(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public virtual int Calculate()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

class CalculationUnitA : CalculationUnit
{
    public CalculationUnitA(string name) : base(name) { }

    public override int Calculate()
    {
        //calculations logic A
    }
}

class CalculationUnitB : CalculationUnit
{
    public CalculationUnitB(string name) : base(name) { }

    public override int Calculate()
    {
        //calculations logic A
    }
}

class CalculationUnitC : CalculationUnit
{
    public CalculationUnitC(string name) : base(name) { }

    public override int Calculate()
    {
        //calculations logic A
    }
}
```

But then I will end up with 50 classes implementing each of the logic...

Thanks

Comment: Did you try googling for _"strategy pattern examples"_ ?

Comment: What is the variance within the `switch`? What changes?

Comment: I tried googling, but didn't find much. Ok, using the pattern in this case, does that mean that I need to have a new class for each of the cases?

Comment: Without seeing your code, we can't recommend an approach that will suit your needs.

Comment: Have you considered polymorphism rather than the switches, instead of a switch statement running the code, the functionality is exposed as a method on a base class. That way instead of a long switch statement you move the 'big piece of code' to the class it relates to and then call the new method to execute the code. Along the same lines as David M's suggestion but not just the logic in the switch moved to a new class.

Comment: Your code is pretty much on the money. The only change you should do make is use a dictionary instead of a list. The lookup to find a calculation unit would be a little faster. (Unless you sort the list by name and use binary search)

Comment: Ok, I have updated my question with some code. joocer, so it is something like you are suggesting?

Comment: MaLio, yeah dictionary is better in my case. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

The [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) helps here by refactoring out the big piece of code in each branch into a separate class (or method). Your switch then becomes simply a case of selecting the appropriate strategy class (or method delegate), which is then executed at the end of the switch statement by a single call. Thus something roughly like this:

```
switch (...)
{
    case ...:
        // Horrible logic;
        break;
    ...
}
```

becomes something like this:

```
ILogicImplementer implementer;
switch (...)
{
    case ...:
        implementer = new FirstCaseImplementer();
        break;
    ...
}
implementer.Implement();
```

You need to refactor the logic into a series of classes implementing a common interface (or extending a common base class), or into a series of methods with compatible signatures so that your strategy can be to select a matching delegate. As Oded implies in his comment, you're not necessarily going to get rid of the `select` doing this, but each case will become a lot smaller.

From your brief description, it does sound like the appropriate approach to make your code simpler and more maintainable.